# C function not returning correct result

Tags: c

I am a beginner of programming, I could not figure out what is wrong with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
long double radius = 0.0L;
long double area = 0.0L;
const long double pi = 3.1415926353890L;
printf("please give the radius ");
scanf("%Lf", &radius);
area = pi * radius * radius;
printf("Area of circle with radius %.3Lf is %.12Lf\n", radius,
area);
return 0;
}
```

This is actually copied directly from a tutorial, when I ran it, I got 0.000000000000 for area, I tried to change to initialized value of area, but the result did not change, can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Update: I ran it in code::blocks, GNU GCC compiler. I tried 5 as the radius, the radius was printed out correctly, but the area was 0.000.......

Changing from long double to double fixed the issue...

Comment: What radius values did you enter? I just ran your code and it appears to work [I get non-zero output and 3.141592635389 for radius of 1]

Comment: Same here, everything looks ok

Comment: Do you by chance run it from an IDE, where stdin is not connected to an input source (i.e. instantly EOF)?

Comment: Yes, it is correct code-wise.

Comment: Apparently everything looks okay but i ran it on code::blocks and it's outputting Zero everytime

Comment: What is your compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly in gcc/g++ compiler but outputs 0.0000.... in case of mingw compiler. This is because mingw uses the Microsoft C library and I seem to remember that that this library has no support for 80bits long double (microsoft C compiler use 64 bits long double for various reasons).

However if you use `double` instead of `long double`, then you will always get expected result.

Comment: You are right. A surprising result indeed. Stupid MS.

Comment: No problem with posted code in MSVC in which `long double` is the same as `double`. Correct result.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've verified it with mingw-w64. The behavior is as described.

Comment: @EugeneSh. MingW is not in the question. If it is faulty that is another issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane it's in the comments... oh wait. Not from the OP

Comment: @WeatherVane: I would guess that means MSVC compiler and MS C library knows to treat `long double` as `double`, but MinGW compiler does not. If `double` is 64 bits and MinGW uses 128 bits for `long double`, then the MS C library may do something strange.

Comment: This all right off topic. Ask the OP. All I know is that MSVC handles the asked question correctly, even without full `long double` support.

Comment: (As I understand the situation,) it would be more precise to say that MinGW uses `MSVCRT.DLL`, which is *not* the C runtime used by current versions of Microsoft's compilers, has not been updated in a very long time (I don't actually know whether it supports `long double` but a claim that it doesn't is totally plausible to me), and which Microsofties will tell you *nobody* is supposed to use anymore; however, it is also the only C runtime that ships with Windows, so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @EugeneSh. build with `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`

Answer (score 2):

Code::Blocks defaults to an old, buggy compiler.  This bug is fixed in [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org) when compiling with the switch `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1`.

You can [download and install](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) this compiler into Code::Blocks and then add that option to the compiler options; or put as the first line of your source code:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
```